# What characteristics of binary space are needed to prove that it is totally disconnected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

In trying to prove that binary space (a homeomorphic space to the better known Cantor Set) is totally disconnected, what traits of the space do I need? Is binary space point-wise open (that would certainly be sufficient)?

As a quick reminder $B$ is the set of infinite sequences of $0$'s and $1$'s where for $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2,y_3,\cdots)$:

$$
d(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
\frac 1 n, & \text{n=min}[i|x_i\neq y_i] \\
0, & x_i=y_i
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: see this answer by Brian Scott http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82796/locally-compact-nonarchimedian-fields

Answer (score 0):

I think the most general fact that applies here (and I can think of) is that every ultrametric space is totally disconnected, as balls are closed.

An ultrametric space is a metric space satisfying strong triangle inequality, i.e. $d(x,z)\leq \max(d(x,y),d(y,z))$. It is routine to check that it is satisfied by the metric you cited, and it is not hard to see that it implies that balls are closed.

Comment: Ok. So open balls are by definition open but also easily shown to be closed. Hence, the space has a basis of clopen sets and is totally disconnected. Do we have to refer to balls for this problem? What about a finite subset of B? Would we then need to use the open balls of the original set and a subspace topology?

Comment: @Musicpulpite: I don't really understand the question. What's wrong with referring to balls? A finite (Hausdorff) space is always discrete (and hence totally disconnected), so the other one seems trivial. A subspace of a Hausdorff space is Hausdorff, and for that matter, a subspace of a totally disconnected space is totally disconnected. Both are mostly straightforward.